# BigQuery append results of query to table with Required fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to append the results of a query to an existing table that has the same schema as the result of the query, except that some of the fields in the existing table are required.

This is the error for all the required fields when I try and run the query:

```
Invalid schema update. Field user has changed mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE
```

When I write the results of the query to a new table it has the same name and types for all the fields, however the mode for all the fields is NULLABLE (except for 1 repeated field). I've tried using `AND user IS NOT NULL` for all the required fields with no luck. I've also tried saving the results of the query to a separate table then modifying its schema, but BQ doesn't allow required fields to be set retroactively on a table.

Answer (score 5):

REQUIRED fields are no longer supported in Standard SQL. If you're using Standard SQL (as opposed to Legacy SQL), they recommend you [change all your REQUIRED fields to NULLABLE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#label_differences).

Edit (10/23/2017): Looks like they've added support for [REQUIRED fields in Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#field_modes).

Comment: Where on that page does it say that?

Comment: Huh, looks like they've added support for required fields: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#field_modes

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I found that creating the table with the schema, and then querying into it specifying the same schema, does work.  Like this:

```
bq mk --schema=myschema.json me.newstuff &&
bq query --format=none --allow_large_results \
  --destination_table=me.newstuff \
  --destination_schema=myschema.json \
  --use_legacy_sql=false \
  "
    SELECT * FROM me.oldstuff
    WHERE data_to_keep is > 0
"
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change schema of the query result to flip NULLABLE to REQUIRED, so the only thing you can do is to change schema of the table to convert REQUIRED column to become NULLABLE (note - if you do it, you won't be able to do the reverse operation later).

Comment: so its basically impossible to append to a table with a query for tables with required fields... That seems like a bit of an oversight.

The only way I can think of making this work is to export the data to GCS as a CSV, then do a load job.

Comment: It is possible in some cases when query produces REQUIRED field, but not in the general case. It seems to me that REQUIRED causes more harm than good, so I would just change schema to be NULLABLE for all fields.

Comment: my tables are already generated and being written to with REQUIRED fields, so I can't really switch the existing tables.

Comment: You can change schema of existing table from REQUIRED to NULLABLE without touching data - it is a compatible schema change.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error "Field  has changed mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE" when I did a load with `bq load` command. The way I solved was to change the schema. Changed the field from "REQUIRED" to "NULLABLE"