# Error Appending Data to Existing Empty Table on BigQuery Using R

Tags: r, google-bigquery, bigrquery

I created an empty table from Big Query GUI with the schema for the `table_name`. Later I'm trying to append data to the existing empty table from `R` using `bigrquery` package.

I have tried below code,

```
upload_job <- insert_upload_job(project = "project_id", 
                                dataset = "dataset_id", 
                                table = "table_name", 
                                values = values_table, 
                                write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND")

wait_for(upload_job)
```

But it is throwing me an  error saying,

> Provided Schema does not match Table. Field alpha has changed mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE [invalid]

My table doesn't have any `NULL` or `NA` in the mentioned column and data_types in the schema matches exactly with the data types of `values_table`.

I tried without creating schema uploading directly from R. While I'm doing that it is automatically converting the mode to `nullable` which is not what I'm looking for.

I also tried by changing `write_dispostion = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"` which is also converting mode to `nullable`.

I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259017/google-bigquery-error-invalid-schema-update-field-has-changed-mode-from-requi/49379445#49379445) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415788/bigquery-append-results-of-query-to-table-with-required-fields) which didn't really help me.

Can someone explain what is happening behind the scenes and what is the best way to upload data without recreating schema.

**Note:** There was a obvious typo error. Earlier it was `wirte_disposition` edited it to `write_disposition`.

Comment: Did you actually use `wirte_disposition`, or did you use `write_disposition`?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. Edited it.